# s3 bucket policy for sso user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I wanted to allow all s3 actions on a particular bucket "test-bucket" for a specific role "test-role". Deny the bucket for all others. The s3 policy I have written :

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Id": "Policy1601973417173",
 "Statement": [
 {
 "Sid": "Allow role test-role",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Principal": {
 "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/test-role"
 },
 "Action": "s3:*",
 "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
 },
 {
 "Sid": "Deny rest",
 "Effect": "Deny",
 "NotPrincipal": {
 "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/test-role"
 },
 "Action": "s3:*",
 "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
 }
 ]
}
```

Even after applying the above policy, the sso users which are mapped to the role "test-role" is getting Access denied on the bucket.

Note : The AWS console shows logged in user as "Federated Login: test-role/sam@abc.com".

I have also tried the "assumed-role" options are still failing. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "AIDA<udserid-1-suppressed>:*",
                        "AIDA<udserid-1-suppressed>",
                        "AIDA<udserid-2-suppressed>:*",
                        "AIDA<udserid-2-suppressed>",
                        "AIDA<udserid-n-suppressed>:*",
                        "AIDA<udserid-n-suppressed>",
                        "111111111111"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That was awesome.. works like a charm :)

I have been trying with the option "aws:username" without any success.

Comment: Can you give example? thanks

Comment: Login to aws with whatever credentials you desire, then run: aws sts get-caller-identity --output json   Use the value of UserId in the policy above.  Hope that helps.